# Will Wither Heads Only Drop In Normal Mode?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was playing in my single player survival in normal mode and found a nether fortress.  I killed around 5 wither skeletons and collected 2 wither heads.  I then switched to easy mode so I wouldn't lose hunger as much and killed around 20 wither skeletons without collecting a single wither head.  I later on switched back to normal mode, killed three wither skeletons and got a head which made we wonder do wither heads only drop in normal and hard mode?

Comment: Well I have been killing wither skeletons on hard mode on my private server with some friends. we have never gotten a wither head despite the tens of wither skeletons we have killed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've had Wither Heads drop on easy before, I believe that the illusion of them only dropping on normal may have been caused by their relatively rare drop rate (2.5%), and you just happening to get lucky when you were on normal. Also, the wiki entry's for both wither skeleton and mob head both have nothing to say on the matter.

Answer (score -1):

When I killed 30 Wither Skeletons in Hard Mode, I got 0 Wither Skeleton heads. I guess it's not Easy or Hard Mode but that they only drop in Normal Mode..

Comment: It looks like the drops are on a percent rate. In theroy, you should have at least 1 drop in 40~ kills. It's not hard set, but on a long enough timeline, the average should look closer to the correct answer.